# Convert canvas in Silverlight to an image stream in C#

Tags: c#, image

In Silverlight, there is a canvas which contains line, rectangle, image.
I want to get an image stream from a canvas. Is it possible?

Comment: _Is it possible?_ Did you try it?

Comment: Try some solutions, and don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get open source FJCore code from https://code.google.com/p/fjcore/. Import FJCore code into your silverlight app, and then use the code below.

```
        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(this.canvas1,null);
        Stream sm = GetBase64Image(wb);       

      public static Stream GetBase64Image(WriteableBitmap bitmap)
        {
            int width = bitmap.PixelWidth;
            int height = bitmap.PixelHeight;
            int bands = 3;
            byte[][,] raster = new byte[bands][,];

            for (int i = 0; i < bands; i++)
            {
                raster[i] = new byte[width, height];
            }

            for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
            {
                for (int column = 0; column < width; column++)
                {
                    int pixel = bitmap.Pixels[width * row + column];
                    raster[0][column, row] = (byte)(pixel >> 16);
                    raster[1][column, row] = (byte)(pixel >> 8);
                    raster[2][column, row] = (byte)pixel;
                }
            }

            ColorModel model = new ColorModel { colorspace = ColorSpace.RGB };
            FluxJpeg.Core.Image img = new FluxJpeg.Core.Image(model, raster);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            JpegEncoder encoder = new JpegEncoder(img, 100, stream);
            encoder.Encode();

            return stream;
        }
```